# Replace All Occurrences using Oracle SQL regexp_replace Case-insensitive

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd love to replace a case-insensitive string for all occurrences

The given query replaces all tons to yard. However, it is case sensitive.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(col_name, 'tons', 'yard') FROM DUAL;
```

How can I write a query that replaces all occurrences regardless of letter cases. I tried this but didn't work:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(col_name, 'tons', 'yard', 'i') FROM DUAL;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the 'i' option is correct, but you're missing two parameters before it.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(<source_string>, <pattern>,<replace_string>, <position>, <occurrence>, <match_parameter>)
```

For position, use 1 to start searching at the beginning. For occurrence, use 0 to replace every occurrence.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(col_name, 'tons', 'yard', 1, 0, 'i') FROM DUAL;
```

[Examples](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html)

[Official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)